# I have in my microservice problem with nx

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile, npm-scripts, nomachine-nx

I am facing next error in deploying storybook its monorepo which needs to publish some packages into nexus also deploy storybook but in deploying one of the service here is design it shows this error with nx i have tried to give permissions and proxy but it doesnt work

```
 >  NX   Running target storybook for project packages/design failed

   Failed tasks:

   - packages/design:storybook

   Hint: run the command with --verbose for more details.


 >  NX   No existing Nx Cloud client and failed to download new version

   Nx Cloud was not used for this command.    You might be offline. Nx Cloud will be re-enabled when you are back online.
```

so my docker file is this

```
*FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/design

COPY package.json ./ 
COPY package-lock.json ./ 
COPY packages/design/package.json ./packages/design/package.json

RUN npm ci

ADD . /usr/src/design

RUN mkdir -p /.npm 
RUN chmod 775 -R /usr/src/design 
RUN chmod 775 -R /tmp/ 
RUN chmod 775 -R /.npm


ENV HTTP_PROXY "something" 
ENV HTTPS_PROXY "something" 
ENV NO_PROXY "something"

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "run", "storybook:design"]
```

i dont know how to make it work i tried all thinks which i could*

Comment: How are you running the container?  (Do you have a `docker run -v` or Compose `volumes:` option that overwrites the source code in the image?)  Have you tried the recommended `--verbose` option to get more details?

Comment: i have used --verbose it shows next error

    },
47
    _currentUrl: 'https://cloud.nx.app/nx-cloud/client/verify',
46
    _timeout: null,
45
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
44
  },
43
  cause: Error: socket hang up
42
      at connResetException (node:internal/errors:720:14)
41
      at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:525:23)
40
      at Socket.emit (node:events:529:35)
39
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1368:12)
38
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
37
    code: 'ECONNRESET'

 @DavidMaze